# How to display a notice if a column in a formula is blank in a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint, excel-formula, formula

I have made a list with three column, Maintenance Cycle (with options such as Monthly, Quarterly etc), Last Maintenance Date (date picker) and Next Maintenance Date (calculated column).

```
=IF([Maintenance Cycle]="Monthly",[Last Maintenance Date]+30,IF([Maintenance Cycle]="Quarterly",[Last Maintenance Date]+90,))
```

Not all the assets in this list will have a "Last Maintenance" column filled in so for those column it calculates from 0 + 30 days or 90 depending on the cycle. Rather than displaying "3/30/1900" in the "Next Maintenance Date" column can I get it to say "No Scheduled Maintenance" or simply be blank whenever there is nothing in the "Last Maintenance Date" column?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you add another test in your formula?

```
=IF([Last Maintenance Date] = "", "No Scheduled Maintenance", [Maintenance Cycle]="Monthly",[Last Maintenance Date]+30,IF([Maintenance Cycle]="Quarterly",[Last Maintenance Date]+90,)))
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thank you! So simple I didn't see it.